# Insert and highlight inserted rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that works well for inserting multiple rows by specifying values for 2 columns. I am not sure how to add in the code to highlight the new inserted rows in some color. Here is my code -

```
Sub Multiplerows()
    Dim rng As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim attrib As String
    Dim BMI As String
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim salesID As Long, salesMkt As String

    Set rRange = Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    rng = InputBox("Enter number:.")
    item = InputBox("Enter name of the Item:.")
    subject = InputBox("Enter name of the sub item:.")
'If rng = 0 Then Exit Sub

    For k = 1 To rng
        Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Next k
   For k = rng To 1 Step -1
    Cells(rRange.Row - k, 10) = item
    Cells(rRange.Row - k, 8) = subject
   Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you want to do (e.g. highlight based on row values), but in your lower loop you could do something like

```
For k = rng To 1 Step -1
    Cells(rRange.Row - k, 10) = item
    Cells(rRange.Row - k, 8) = subject
    ActiveSheet.Rows(rRange.Row - k).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next k
```

This would highlight the new row as bright red. Change the RGB values to whatever you like.